# Is this domain vulnerable to XSS attack

Tags: web-application, xss, vulnerability

I have a domain which when opened shows :

[image]

Whatever I type after `xyz.com/whatever` appears on the title bar as `xyz.com/whatever` , if i write `xyz.com/stackoverflow` the title bar shows the same as `xyz.com/stackoverflow`.

Is there any XSS that i can perform here??

Comment: Why do you think that this behavior means that it is vulnerable to XSS?

Comment: If i write `xyz.com/<script>....</script>` in the url then the same appears in the titlebar, so i think can i do some xss as `<script>`  tag is roaming freely.

Comment: then you might want to mention that behavior

Comment: and then it's not the *domain* that might be vulnerable, but the *site*

Comment: For sites that don't set the `<title>` element, the browser displays the URL as the title. Pretty sure that's what's happening here, and it's not at all exploitable. Check the actual HTTP response to see what's in the body (specifically, whether it contains HTML elements from your request), though. It *could* have an XSS injection point at the part inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not. XSS is only possible when the browser interpret the response from the server as HTML. This is triggered by the following response header:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

In your case, it seems that the browser interprets the response as text, as indicated by this header:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

In that case, the browser does not interpret HTML and tags will show up as tags.

I base this conclusion on the font of your screenshot. Of course it could also be a HTML page with a particular font.

Sometimes it is still possible to trick the browser into rendering HTML, even when the content-type says otherwise. This is because browsers sometimes do MIME-type sniffing: they try to guess the content type of the page.